# Regular Expression for IMDB Database

Tags: java, regex

I'm a basic coder and very new to regular expression. I need to filter the below input to the output specified as below which I need it to feed as an input for my assignment task. Can any one help me out in writing the regular expression alone or at least a guidance? Also is there any other method to do this?

Input:

```
A Gathering of Eagles (1963)  (uncredited)  [Mrs. Josten]           
The Creed of Violence (????)  (rumored) 
A Life of Her Own (1950)  (uncredited)  [Model]         
Pourvu qu'elles soient douces (Libertine II) (1989)  [William]  <6>
A Virgin in Hollywood (1953)  [Darla Sloan]  <1>            
Gordon-Levitt, Joseph   (500) Days of Summer (2009)
Aaron Slick from Punkin Crick (1952)  (uncredited)  [Showgirl]      
Cruisin (On a Saturday Night) (2009) {{SUSPENDED}}  [Officer Hernandez]
Angels in Disguise (1949)  (uncredited)  [Reception Nurse]          
The Candid Camera Story (Very Candid) of the Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer Pictures 1937 Convention (1937)  (uncredited)  [Himself]
Annie Get Your Gun (1950)  (uncredited)  [Carriage Woman]   
From the Ashes (2011/I)  (voice)  [Himself - Narrator]      
Bachelor in Paradise (1961)  (uncredited)  [Minor Role]
The Deep Blue Goodbye (????)  (rumored)  [Travis McGee]
Southpaw (????)  (uncredited)  [Spectator/High Roller]
```

Output

```
A Gathering of Eagles (1963)
A Life of Her Own (1950)
Pourvu qu'elles soient douces (Libertine II) (1989)
A Virgin in Hollywood (1953)
Gordon-Levitt, Joseph   (500) Days of Summer (2009)
Aaron Slick from Punkin Crick (1952)
Cruisin (On a Saturday Night) (2009)
Angels in Disguise (1949)
The Candid Camera Story (Very Candid) of the Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer Pictures 1937 Convention (1937)
Annie Get Your Gun (1950)
From the Ashes (2011/I)
Bachelor in Paradise (1961)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it

```
^.*?\(\d\d\d\d.*?\)
```

in Java, try

```
Pattern.compile("^.*?\\(\\d\\d\\d\\d.*?\\)", Pattern.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: I'm coding in Java and I used the following code which didn't print anything.

    `String movieName = str.split("^.*?\\(\\d*?\\)")[0];`

Comment: did you escape your \ in java?

Comment: Yea... I did escape \

Comment: try using a regex with multiline

Comment: Everything working perfectly.